# Куда девать файл загруженный через ajax, если просто закрыть страницу заказа?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Допустим я в форме выбираю файл, он загружается на сервер, обрабатывается, возвращается превью, но в этот момент, я просто закрываю вкладку. Как бы форма не отправлена, а файлы лишние загружены. Что в таких случаях делают? Я уже думал эти файлы сохранять во временной папке, при нажатии submit эти файлы идут в нужную дерикторию, а все файлы, например вчерашние, во временной папке удалять.

Comment: Ну по хорошему у файлов есть хранилище, а лучше всего если будет какая то таблица в бд, которая отслеживает их состояние по отношению к формам. Т.е. если форма была отменена, то у формы нет (например) confirmation токена. А раз самой формы нет, то и картинки не нужны. Можно просто хранить список форм, иметь связь к таблице, в которой будут картинки для формы. Если форма не апрувнута - удалить записи о форме, а за ними и данные из бд о картинках уходят на скрипт по удалению файлов. Достаточно тяжелое решение, но надежное ( в рамках вашей проблемы).

Comment: @alexoander Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментариq в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Файл имеет дату создания, зная ее вы можете удалить его по этому атрибуту из какого либо места программы или воспользоваться доступным сервисом (например с помощью демона cron), а то есть создать условие критерием которого будет установленное время жизни файла при превышении которого необходимый файл надо удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Ну по хорошему у файлов есть хранилище, а лучше всего если будет какая то таблица в бд, которая отслеживает их состояние по отношению к формам. Т.е. если форма была отменена, то у формы нет (например) confirmation токена. А раз самой формы нет, то и картинки не нужны. Можно просто хранить список форм, иметь связь к таблице, в которой будут картинки для формы. Если форма не апрувнута - удалить записи о форме, а за ними и данные из бд о картинках уходят на скрипт по удалению файлов. Достаточно тяжелое решение, но надежное ( в рамках вашей проблемы).